# After launch a package procedure spring throws java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, plsql

I'm calling a procedure from an Oracle package(PL/SQL) with a JPARepository:

```
@Procedure("pkg_user.create_user")
String createUser(String user);
```

This one works properly. But then my application is throwing a java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException and the others services are not working.

```
After launch a package procedure spring throws java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms
```

It seems like after launching the procedure it lost the connection with the DB.

I'm using Java 7 and Oracle 18c.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.